# I need a simple sql query for finding words which has specific characters

Tags: mysql

I wasnt an sql query which returns a word which has those characters only.
Eg: If I give characters as d,o,k,c,l.  Then query should return dock, doll, all possible english words. I already have english word list in my database.

I've tried this query,

```
select col_name from TName
Where
col_name REGEXP "^[d|o|k|c|l]{2,}$"
```

But, this always returned 0 rows. Please help me out will mysql query to fix this.``

Comment: Inside a regular expression set, the `|` character takes on a more literal meaning.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
select col_name 
from TName
Where col_name REGEXP "\w[dockcl]+\w"
```

Comment: Even now it returned 0 rows. REGEXP "^[dokcl]{2,}$" is returning 0 rows. it returns bunch of rows when I type it as REGEXP "^[dokcl]{2,}", but it has different meaning so is the result. Can you please help me you. keeping $ in last never gives me any result

Comment: Do your fields have spaces at the end?

Comment: REGEXP "\w[dockcl]+\w" has a different meaning isn't it. It returns the words which has other characters a part from what has been specified.

Comment: Tadman, It doesn't has any spaces in end. Ive used it varchar and even trimed them.

Comment: I just figured out that, 2 extra character have been inserted at the end. those characters are not visible. They are not spaces. help me out. I'm stuck.

Comment: @user1710675 actually mysql is not the right place for using `Regex`. If i understand you corrected, In a column within a row, there is a string like 'clog, dock, doll, fog, hello world' and you only want to extract 'clog, dock, doll` right? well i think its possible but it requires you to have humungous code on it, `REGEXP` test only the column if the string contains the pattern, but not to extract string on it.